# Filtering out the List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of objects, I want to filter on certain criteria. so I have

```
List<person> plist= Person.getPersonList();
```

`List<person>`  has around 400 records and each record has FirstName, lastName, Home address, Phone number, Id. user can enter any search criteria in the search box
and I want to filter pList and display the results that matches the search criteria so for e.g
if the user enters FisrtName "te

then i want to filter out the pList showing all the names that starts with te.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

-anjali

Comment: i want to do on multiple fields like first name last name so the user can enter te as the first name and in the same text box they can enter te as the last name

Comment: why did I get -4 here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List plist= Person.getPersonList();
var filtered = plist.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("te").ToList();
```

to search for more then 1 value at once:

```
List plist= Person.getPersonList();
var filtered = plist.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("te") || x.OtherProperty.StartsWith("some other value")).ToList();
```

this is all pretty easy to mess around with yourself tho, so I think you have the basis
operations that you need right here.

Comment: @HackyStack sry, now it will.

Comment: I removed my comment after you fixed it, but for posterity, you originally had '.Contains' instead of '.StartsWith'.  It is correct now.

Comment: Thanks Thousand. Although, i don't know why there is -4 in front of my post.